# Unable to obtain the correct CSS layout on iOS devices (Eg: iPhones)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm unable to obtain the correct CSS design layout when viewed on an iPhone while when I view the same code on a Android, the CSS design layout works well. There are unnecessary spaces in the layout at some sections and some section even overlap each other.

Code:

(HTML sample code)

```
            <!-- ABOUT US SECTION(GLIMPSE OF US) -->
            <div class="about-section">
                <div class="about-us">
                    <h1 class="about-web">A GLIMPSE<br>OF US</h1>
                    <h1 class="about-mobile">A GLIMPSE OF US</h1>
                    <div class="text-plus-pointers">
                        <p class="about-us-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
                        <div class="adjectives">
                            <h1 class="the-value">LOREM IPSUM</h1>
                            <div class="frame14-list">
                                <div class="frame14"><img class="frame14-img" src="res/Check circle.png">
                                    <h1 class="frame14-text">valueone</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="frame14"><img class="frame14-img" src="res/Check circle.png">
                                    <h1 class="frame14-text">valuetwo</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="frame14"><img class="frame14-img" src="res/Check circle.png">
                                    <h1 class="frame14-text">valuethree</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

(Corresponding CSS sample code)

```
    .about-web{
        display: none;
    }
    .about-section {
        background: #F5F5F5;
        height: 130.5vw;
    }
    .about-us{
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-self: center;
        gap: 6vw;
        height: fit-content;
        width: 88%;
    }
    .about-mobile{
        display: flex;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 9vw;
        line-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        letter-spacing: -0.04em;
        color: #222222;
    }
    .text-plus-pointers{
        width: 100%;
        gap: 5vw;
    }
    .about-us-text{
        font-size: 3.5vw;
        height: fit-content;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .the-value{
        display: flex;
        width: 65%;
        height: 100%;
        font-size: 5.5vw;
        line-height: 6.2vw;
    }
    .adjectives{
        height: fit-content;
        align-items: flex-start;
        padding: 11vw 9vw 11vw 9vw;
        gap: 3vw;
    }
    .frame14-list{
        width: 100%;
        gap: 1vw;
    }
    .frame14{
        height: 8vw;
        gap: 3vw;
    }
    .frame14-img {
        width: 5.5vw;
        height: 5.5vw;
    }
    .frame14-text{
        font-size: 5.5vw;
    }
```

I've used all the properties like this only without any modification?

Need help with it. If there are any extensions that need to be added so that this code is also compatible with iOS smartphones.